# Retrofit with an old school service

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit

I'm using an external service like :
http://domain.com/free/v1/servicename.ext?format=json&num_of_days=4

I try to use Retrofit like that :

```
@GET("/free/v1/servicename.ext?format=json&num_of_days={numOfDays}")
void serviceName(@Path("numOfDays") int numOfDays, Callback<Result> callback);
```

but an exception is thrown :

```
URL query string must not have replace block.
```

Is it compatible with this kind of url ?

Answer (score 36):

It absolutely is compatible with it!

You can't use `@Path` inside of the query parameters. That annotation is only for replacements inside the path.

The `@Query` parameter allows for creating dynamic query parameters.

```
@GET("/free/v1/servicename.ext?format=json")
void serviceName(@Query("num_of_days") int numOfDays, Callback<Result> callback);
```

Comment: TRUE that helped me much, Thank you! 
Replaced:

@GET("/api/access_token?nickname={nickname}&password={password}")
    Observable<AuthorizationToken> authorizationToken(
            @Path("nickname") String userName,
            @Path("password") String password
    );

With:
@GET("/api/access_token?")
Observable<AuthorizationToken> authorizationToken(
            @Query("nickname") String nickname,
            @Query("password") String password
    );

And it works like a charm.

Comment: Why retrofit 2 must set `baseUrl()` ?  I think `@GET('http://www.google.com/path')` is much easier to use.