# Array Query Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I need to send a get parameters as: `origin=val1,val2` and `destination=val1,val2` but I cant find a way.

I´m trying:

```
String url = "/api/directions?origin={olon},{olat}&destination={dlon},{dlat}R";

@POST(url) void getInfoBetween(@Path("olon") double originLon, @Path("olan") double originLat,@Path("dlon") double destLon,    @Path("dlan") double destLan,Callback<MapsResponse> callback);
```

But I get:

```
 Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: LocationService.getInfoBetween: 
 URL query string "origin={olon},{olat}" must not have replace block. 
 For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

Why am I getting it?

Comment: Not sure if this will help but here's something similar: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25670615/3531756)

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure that that is also the problem here: `@Path` should only be used in the path part of the URL, not for query parameters. Use `@Query` for those.