# How do I use @Path in query string in Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an URL like `http://www.example.com/index.php?apiex/teacher/2` and I want `http://www.example.com/index.php?apiex/teacher/{teacher_id}`, not like this `http://www.example.com/index.php?apiex/teacher?teacher_id=2`.

Using like `getTeacher(@Path("teacher_id") String teacherId)` gives me an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "apiex/teacher/{teacher_id}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

My Retrofit interface is like this:

```java
@GET("apiex/teacher/{teacher_id}")
Observable<List<Teachers>>getTeacher(@Path("teacher_id") String teacherId);
```

and the base URL is `http://www.example.com/index.php?`. And also I cant remove `?` from this. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25670615/5962715), but I wanted it like above.

Comment: Can you show your Retrofit interface? What's the annotation right before `getTeacher()`?

Comment: @azizbekian I have added that

Answer (score 1):

make the baseurl like this http://www.example.com/index.php/ instead of 
http://www.example.com/index.php? as it sees what after ? as query that's why it says that the block after the ? is query

Comment: This should be correct one, because anything after "?" is considered as query parameter.

Comment: @azizbekian I know that but I done this using codeigniter so I want dynamic url after ?

Comment: if I removed the ? it will not work or give the response

Comment: Maybe you can handle it with [intercepting](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) and replacing parameters.